# How to Replace \n, b and single quotes from Raw File from GitHub?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to download file from GitHub(raw file) and then run this file as .sql file.

```
import snowflake.connector
from codecs import open
import logging
import requests
from os import getcwd
import os
import sys

#logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='C:/Users/abc/Documents/Test.log',
    level=logging.INFO
)

url = "https://github.com/raw/abc/master/file_name?token=Anvn3lJXDks5ciVaPwA%3D%3D"
directory = getcwd()
filename = os.path.join(getcwd(),'VIEWS.SQL')
r = requests.get(url)
filename.decode("utf-8")

f = open(filename,'w')
f.write(str(r.content))

with open(filename,'r') as theFile, open(filename,'w') as outFile:
    data = theFile.read().split('\n')
    data = theFile.read().replace('\n','')
    data = theFile.read().replace("b'","")
    data = theFile.read()
    outFile.write(data)
```

However I get this error

> syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'b'

My converted sql file has b at the beginning and bunch of newline \n characters in the file. Also the entire output file is in single quotes 'text'. Can anyone help me get rid of these? Looks like replace isn't working.

OS: Windows
Python Version: 3.7.0

Comment: **Don’t** use `str()` on a bytes object to convert it to a string! The response object has a `.text` attribute you should use instead. Or open the file in binary mode with `'wb'`. In other contexts, you want to *decode*, so `bytesval.decode(some_codec)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You introduced a `b'..` prefix by converting the `response.content` bytes value to a string with `str()`:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("https://github.com/raw/abc/master/file_name?token=Anvn3lJXDks5ciVaPwA%3D%3D")
>>> r.content
b'Not Found'
>>> str(r.content)
"b'Not Found'"
```

Of course, the specific dummy URL you gave in your question produces a 404 Not Found response, hence the `Not Found` content of the response body:

```
>>> r.status_code
404
```

so the contents in this demonstration are not actually all that useful. However, even for your real URL you probably want to test for a 200 status code before moving to write the data to a file!

What is going wrong in the above is that `str(bytesvalue)` converts a bytes object to its *representation*. You'd normally want to *decode* a bytes value with a text codec, using the [`bytes.decode()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode). But because you are writing the data to a file here, you should instead just open the file in *binary* mode and write the bytes object without decoding:

```
r = requests.get(url)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

The `'wb'` mode opens the file for writing in binary mode. Writing binary content to a binary file is the most efficient; decoding it first then writing to a text file requires that it is *encoded* again. Better to avoid doing double work.

As a side note: there is no need to join a local filename with `getcwd()`; relative paths always end up in the current working directory, and otherwise it's better to use `os.path.abspath(filename)`.

You *could* also trust that GitHub sets the correct character set in the Content-Type headers and have response decode the value to str for you in the form of the [`response.text` attribute](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content):

```
r = requests.get(url)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(r.text)
```

but again, that's really doing extra work for nothing, first decoding the binary content from the request, then encoding again when writing to a text file.

Finally, for larger file responses it is better to *stream* the data and copy it directly to a file. The [`shutil.copyfileobj()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) can take a raw response fileobject directly, provided you enable transparent transport decompression:

```
import shutil

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        # enable transparent transport decompression handling
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your version of Python/OS it could be as simple as changing the file to read/write in binary (and if they're still there then altering where you have the `replace`s):

```
with open(filename,'rb') as theFile, open(filename,'wb') as outFile:
    outfile.write(str(r.content))
    data = theFile.read().split('\n')
    data = data.replace('\n','')
    data = data.replace("b'","")
    outFile.write(data)
```

It would help to have a copy of the file and the line the error is occurring on.

Comment: DeCottis-Mauro Don't think it works. It's giving me below error now:     **outFile.write(str(r.content))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

Comment: Can you try it removing the str() around r.content in that line?